# Gitignore GLOB pattern to track files without file extension

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to track the files which have no file extension. I am using following .gitignore file

```
.gitignore
*.*     # THIS CATCHES EVERYTHING
!*.asm

# I TRIED THE BELOW directives
#*.\d{1}*  
#*.[?]*
#*.[?*]
```

Point me in the right direction!

Comment: Why do you ignore `.gitignore`? In many cases this prevents forkers from adding binary files to your repository...

Comment: @CommuSoft I see no use of tracking the changes in `.gitignore` viz exclude list. I didn't understood *how would it prevent someone from adding a binary content?* will you explain that.

Comment: Well in a project where multiple people collaborate, by adding the `.gitignore` people that clone the repository will by default have a `.gitignore` with these settings. So given such person makes a contribution to your project, compiles the code, then he will not - by accident - add for instance an `.exe` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this .gitignore:

```
.gitignore
**/*.*
!*.asm
```

Comment: This still does ignore the files with no file_extension. I need to track the files which have no file_extension.

Comment: You want track and ingore files with no file extension at the same time?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for the confusion, It seems I made a serious typing mistake. I wish to track files with no file_extension.

Comment: Your .gitignore file works then. I've just checked it.

Comment: plz look at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_OcX1Wr8s5WQmtQdDk4NTVpbHM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Loose the extension in the second line of your file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65448/discussion-between-vvy-and-akond).